Embed Published Google Sheet in GitHub md file
Trying to embed this spreadsheet into this md file on GitHub.  As you can see, for whatever reason, only the link is showing up.
Can this be done so that the published sheet appears withing the md file?  I just want those who access this directory to be able to see the outline by week.  Is there another solution using GitHub that I should try?

This probably cannot be done. You can find more information here.

GitHub Markdown does not support iframes.
You need to export your google sheet somehow to a markdown table. One way would be to download it as a csv (File -> Download -> CSV) and then use pandoc to convert to markdown:
pandoc -f csv input.csv -o output.md


I did not realize that.  Thank you.
